# Is it possible to rename an App id's name in the provisioning portal

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I created a new App id in the provisioning portal but accidentally gave it the incorrect id (I created it as com.company.A but meant to put com.company.B) and gave it the name B.

As its not possible to delete app ids from the portal I want to create the correct one of com.company.B however I want to name it B, but this name is already taken up with the incorrect app id. So I want to rename the incorrect one from B to "B Incorrect" or something similar.

Comment: Apple has changed their dev portal recently. Now you can delete App Id. Apple hasn't provided a way to rename app id though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Its not possible to rename App Id.

Now its possible to delete app id:

Click on App ID-> Settings->scroll down and press delete !

Comment: @Mungbeans, its possible...even I removed all old app id :)